# use dask to store larger then memory csv file(s) to hdf5 file

Tags: csv, hdf5, dask

Task: read larger than memory csv files, convert to arrays and store in hdf5.
One simple way is to use pandas to read the files in chunks
but I wanted to use dask, so far without success:

Latest attempt:

```
fname='test.csv'
dset = dd.read_csv(fname, sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None)
dset.to_records().to_hdf5('/tmp/test.h5', '/x')
```

How could I do this?

Actually, I have a set of csv files representing 2D slices of a 3D array
that I would like to assemble and store. A suggestion on how to do the latter
would be welcome as well.

Given the comments below, here is one of many variations I tried:

```
dset  = dd.read_csv(fname, sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None, dtype='f8')
shape = (num_csv_records(fname), num_csv_cols(fname))
arr   = da.Array( dset.dask, 'arr12345', (500*10, shape[1]), 'f8', shape)
da.to_hdf5('/tmp/test.h5', '/x', arr)
```

which results in the error:
KeyError: ('arr12345', 77, 0)

Comment: yet another variation:
 
    dset = dd.read_csv(fname, sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None, dtype=dtype)
    dset = dset.values
   arr  = da.Array( dset.dask, dset.name, (500*10, shape[1]), dset.dtype, shape)
   da.to_hdf5('/tmp/test.h5', '/x', arr)
yields the message
KeyError: ('values-24e01610066a0b145ae6116c20e39a0f', 62, 0)

Comment: Why `to_records()`? HDF5 stores tables too, and this would appear to be the natural representation of your CSV data.

Comment: no, the natural representation is a multidimensional array (actually a 3D array). The csv files are an artifact of a matlab simulation.

Comment: You might be better to load the array with delayed [`np.loadtext`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), and then use `dask.array.from_delayed` and `dask.array.stack`, since you know the size up-front.
Still, you don't say *how* your current method isn't working...

Comment: the data does not fit in memory. A simple solution is to use pandas to read the data frame in chunks.

The question I had was to get any one way to get this working using dask. None of the variations using dset.values,  arr=da.Array(dset.dask,...),da.to_hdf5(),  da.store()... worked, each with confounding error messages. E.g., both the above code snippet and a version using da.store() yielded `('values-24e01610066a0b145ae6116c20e39a0f', 62, 0)`
Rechunking the array with 'auto' for the row dimension yielded
`Cant broadcast (84543, 1368) -> (20000, 1368)`, .... and so forth

Comment: It would be better if you presented some of these individually, it's very hard to grasp from these comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to do something like the following. The real crux of the problem is, that in the read-csv case, dask doesn't know the number of rows of the data before a full load, and therefore the resultant data-frame has an unknown length (as is the usual case for data-frames). Arrays, on the other hand, generally need to know their complete shape for most operations. In your case you have extra information, so you can sidestep the problem.

Here is an example.

Data

```
0,1,2
2,3,4
```

Code

```
dset = dd.read_csv('data', sep=',', skiprows=0, header=None)
arr = dset.astype('float').to_dask_array(True)
arr.to_hdf5('/test.h5', '/x')
```

Where "True" means "find the lengths", or you can supply your own set of values.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `to_hdf` method on dask dataframes instead of on dask arrays

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.to_hdf('myfile.hdf', '/data')
```

Alternatively, you might consider using parquet.  This will be faster and is simpler in many ways

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df.to_parquet('myfile.parquet')
```

For more information, see the documentation on creating and storing dask dataframes: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html

### For arrays

If for some reason you *really* want to convert to a dask array first then you'll need to figure out how many rows each chunk of your data has and assign that to chunks attribute.  See http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html#unknown-chunks .  I don't recommend this approach though, it's needlessly complex.